# How to flip a card while scaling it in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I'm trying to take a card UIView object, which has both back and front image subviews in it, and flip it while scaling it larger until mid flip and then scaling it back down. I have it working with just the flipping part, using `UIView.transition(with:duration:options:animations:completion:)`, but this doesn't seem to be the correct solution, as all animations in the block only occur halfway through the full animation, which makes sense, since that's the point the views need to be added/removed.

I'm guessing I need to drop down to a lower level here, but I'm not that familiar with animations beyond the UIView layer. Any suggestions on how to add this scaling functionality to the card flip?

Comment: I think you should be able to do it in chunks of `UIView.animate` and schedule them one after the other.

Comment: @ShamasS Can you go into more detail on this? I'd love to be able to do it this way, basically just implementing `UIView.transition(with` in a custom UIView.animate, but I'm struggling figuring out how.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the both sides of the card under the layers of the view, you can do so by setting the `contents` of a `CALayer`. Then you apply the `CABasicAnimation` on the sublayers.

This is a simple demo which should run on the playground, without scaling implemented, you can modify the matrix by `CATransform3DRotate(t:angle:x:y:z:)` yourself.

```
var t = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI), 0, 1, 0)
t.m34 = 0.001 // set a 3D perspective to simulate real flipping
let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
anim.byValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: t)
anim.duration = 3
anim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
anim.isRemovedOnCompletion = true

let cardContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100))
cardContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

// layer1: front side of the card
let layer1 = CALayer()
layer1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
layer1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
layer1.isDoubleSided = false

// layer2: back side of the card
let layer2 = CALayer()
layer2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
layer2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
layer2.isDoubleSided = false
layer2.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI), 0, 1, 0)

cardContainer.layer.addSublayer(layer1)
cardContainer.layer.addSublayer(layer2)
layer1.add(anim, forKey: "anim1")
layer2.add(anim, forKey: "anim2")
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up! Unfortunately I'm stuck using UIViews and can't drop into to the layer level. One of the views I'm flipping isn't a straight image (it's a lottie animation).

Comment: you may try the CoreAnimation solution still, since all UIViews would have a _backing layer_ which is of a CALayer instance, apply the animation on them instead. (Actually UIView animations are encapsulations of CoreAnimation APIs, they're delegated to `actionForLayer:forKey:`)

remember to set `.isDoubleSided` to `false`.